# Horrible kerning in LibreOffice

Tags: macos, libreoffice

You'd think that kerning would be the #1 thing to get right in a text processor, but LibreOffice shows me this:

[image]

Font is Palatino, with bold applied.

How to fix this? Note that the kerning is correct when I un-apply bold:

[image]

Comment: How is the kerning if you simply apply a bold style to the Palatino font?

Comment: @Misha: sorry, I was unclear, there is only one version of the Palatino font. That's exactly what I did (apply bold to normal Palatino font).

Comment: Can you include both images of with and without boldface applied? Is there a space between m and T?

Comment: @slhck: see edit, and yes, there's a space between the m and T.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit, I don't see the problem in your case, apart from a too narrow space, perhaps. But it could well be that the problem is just the on-screen display whereas print output looks correct. LibreOffice would just use the kerning tables from the font anyway and I guess it's very hard to get *that* wrong. Drawing glyphs to the screen in a pleasing manner *is* hard in contrast.

Comment: Yes, the space is way too narrow, and the letters in Problem are more far apart in the bold version than they should be.

Comment: Also, it's been a while since I actually needed to print something out, I'd argue that on-screen display is equally if not more important. I certainly couldn't care less about how it looks when printed.

Comment: Well, ODT is certainly not a final format you give to someone else. PDF should work the same as printed.

Answer (score 1):

If when you toggle *Pair Kerning* in *Format -> Character -> Position -> Spacing*, then I'd have to say it was Xft-related. What LO version are you on?

If I recall, Libre Office uses Xft settings. I've had text rendering issues with certain version of **libxft**, so it may be worth rolling back to an older version if it's been updated recently.

Otherwise, have you made any recent changes to **.Xresources**?